# Calculate sum, counts in many to many

Tags: mysql

Greetings I am trying to sum up expense value for each transaction.

Association table.

```
  **Assoc table schema**


    | PK_id | FK_transaction | FK_Expense |
    |-------|----------------|------------|
    |     1 |              1 |         85 |
    |     2 |              2 |         81 |
    |     3 |              3 |         77 |
    |     4 |              4 |         83 |
    |     5 |              5 |         84 |
    |     6 |              6 |        105 |
    |     7 |              7 |        104 |
    |     8 |              8 |         71 |
    |     9 |              8 |         88 |
    |    10 |              8 |         90 |
```

Transaction table

```
**Transaction table schema**

| PK_id | type | value | confirmed_value    |
|-------|------|-------|--------------------|
|     1 |    1 |   3.2 |               0    |
|     2 |    1 |  23.2 |               0    |
|     3 |    1 |  33.2 |               0    |
|     4 |    1 |  43.2 |              11.00 |
|     5 |    1 |  53.2 |               0    |
|     6 |    1 |  63.2 |               0    |
|     7 |    1 |  73.2 |               0    |
|     8 |    1 |  83.2 |              66.00 |
|     9 |    1 |  93.2 |               0    |
|    10 |    1 | 133.2 |              77.00 |
|    11 |    1 | 123.2 |               0    |
```

Expences Table

```
| PK_id | value |
|-------|-------|
|    85 |   3.2 |
|    81 |  23.2 |
|    77 |  33.2 |
|    83 |  43.2 |
|    84 |  53.2 |
|   105 |  63.2 |
|   104 |  73.2 |
|    71 |  83.2 |
|    88 |  93.2 |
|    90 | 133.2 |
```

Result ::

```
| PK_id | value | confirmed_value |
|-------|-------|-----------------|
|     1 |   3.2 |               0 |
|     2 |  23.2 |               0 |
|     3 |  33.2 |               0 |
|     4 |  43.2 |              11 |
|     5 |  53.2 |               0 |
|     6 |  63.2 |               0 |
|     7 |  73.2 |               0 |
|     8 |  83.2 |              66 |
|     8 |  93.2 |              66 |
|     8 | 133.2 |              66 |
```

Desired - before calculations ( just to give u the idea )

```
| PK_id | value | confirmed_value |
|-------|-------|-----------------|
|     1 |   3.2 |               0 |
|     2 |  23.2 |               0 |
|     3 |  33.2 |               0 |
|     4 |  43.2 |              11 |
|     5 |  53.2 |               0 |
|     6 |  63.2 |               0 |
|     7 |  73.2 |               0 |
|     8 |  309.6 |             66 |
```

**Full desired result**

count matching values COUNT(confirmed_value = value ) 
count entries that not match  COUNT(confirmed_value != value )

/\ Calculate value of confirmed values
?? sum(transactions.confirmed_value)

and calculate value itself

```
Should be a row result ( example )
=======================================================================================================================
MATCHED | NOT_MATCHED | SUM(of values) | COUNT(of confirmed equal to value ) | COUNT(of confirmed ! equal to value ) 
=======================================================================================================================
 1      |    10       |    3003.22     |         3                           |  10
=======================================================================================================================
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ab102/9

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT transactions.PK_id,
       SUM(expenses.value),
       transactions.confirmed_value
FROM `assoc`
JOIN `expenses` ON `assoc`.`FK_Expense` = `expenses`.`PK_id`
JOIN `transactions` ON `assoc`.`FK_transaction` = `transactions`.`PK_id`
GROUP BY transactions.PK_id,
         transactions.confirmed_value
```

Fiddle Demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ab102/14